# how to differentiate between two threads

Tags: java, multithreading

I have the following code in my program:

```
Thread getUsersist, getChatUsers;

getUsersList = new Thread(this, "getOnlineUsers");
getUsersList.start();
getChatUsers = new Thread(this, "getChatUsers");
getChatUsers.start();
```

In run(), I wish to know which thread is using run(). If its "getOnlineUsers" i will do something, If it is "getChatUsers" I will do something else. So how do I know which thread is using run()?

Comment: What do you mean by, "using run()"? Do you mean, which thread is currently running?

Comment: yes. When i say *.start(), it calls run() isn't it. So in run() I want to know which thread called it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `run()`, you can do:

```
Thread.currentThread().getName()
```

to get either "getOnlineUsers" or "getChatUsers" and take a different code path accordingly. That said, it seems like a rather fragile design to me and I'd imagine you'd be far better off with separate classes for each thread.

Comment: You don't need `Thread.currentThread()`. `run()` is a method of the Thread class descendant.

Comment: +1 for noting this approach is sketchy and better alternatives should  be considered.

Comment: @Marcelo: But the run() method of Runnable is not.

Comment: +1: "separate classes for each thread": or at least a property on the Runnable.

Comment: yup, I am implementing Runnable. And this method works, unlike Marcelo's although I dont understand why.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (getName().equals("getOnlineUsers")) {
    doOneThing();
else if (getName().equals("getChatUsers")) {
    doAnotherThing();
} else {
    throw Up();
}
```

EDIT: Ignore this answer. Read the accepted answer.

Comment: But the `this` in his code example is a `Runnable`, not a `Thread`. `getName()` is not available.

Comment: I tried this, but simply doing System.out.println(getName()) gives me some other thread name, not the one that I need("getOnlineUsers","getChatUSers").